# Bootstrap Spacing classes not working

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, padding, margins

I am trying to add spacing to my div/ul as shown in Bootstrap Utilities Documents.  But it's not working at all and I couldn't even trace the class in Firebug.

http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/utilities/#spacing

My HTML Code

```
<div>
    <ul class="p-t-20">
        <li><a href="#" class="fa fa-calendar fa-lg"> Events</a> </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I tried to use both m-t-20 or p-t-20 or other combinations.  But it doesn't work at all.  How could I use these bootstrap classes?

And I am using these Bootstrap CSS files.  Am I using the wrong version?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha512-dTfge/zgoMYpP7QbHy4gWMEGsbsdZeCXz7irItjcC3sPUFtf0kuFbDz/ixG7ArTxmDjLXDmezHubeNikyKGVyQ==" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-aUGj/X2zp5rLCbBxumKTCw2Z50WgIr1vs/PFN4praOTvYXWlVyh2UtNUU0KAUhAX" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Comment: Your link points to bootstraps version 4, while you're including version 3.3.5 in you project. Maybe thats the issue, that spacing doesn't exist in v3.3.5?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes you are using older version of bootstrap. **[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/rgpL0a3k/)** 3.3.5 that's why it is not working

If you use V4.0 , **[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/trg18kqv/1/)** here its working fine

As Vucko mentioned, your Bootstrap version does not have the classes you used in your HTML structure..

```
<div>
    <ul class="p-t-20">
        <li><a href="#" class="fa fa-calendar fa-lg"> Events</a> </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 136):

**Today 2021 in boostrap 5 Margin and Padding :**

***Margin***
Margin top: mt-value
Margin right: me-value
Margin bottom: mb-value
Margin left: ms-value

***Padding***
Padding top: pt-value
Padding right: pe-value
Padding bottom: pb-value
Paddig left: ps-value.
***Where the range for the value is 0 to 5***

Comment: any reasoning for using e and s instead of very obvious r and l ?

Comment: The reason is due to the text direction of LTR and RTL and it now means `S`tart and `E`nd and the margin will swap automagically sides depending on the `direction` property.

Comment: Ahh classic, was trying to use the Bootstrap 4 utilities instead. For those looking for the Bootstrap 5 utilities, I believe this is the link: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/flex/.

Comment: @MarioFigueiredo sorry, but LTR and RTL have left and right in their actual acronyms lol

Comment: @quemeful yes, and the start is different for the two depending on which comes first. 
right is start in "R(ight)T(o)L(eft)" but is the end in "LeftToRight". hence the distinction by S(tart) and E(nd) instead of the old L(eft) and R(ight)

Comment: @MarioFigueiredo Unfortunately, unfortunately, neither bootstrap 4, nor 5 have any run-time or context-sensitive orientations. If you are setting an starting margin for any element, for example, inside a d-flex div, and set it with "ms-5", it only means start margin in "LTR" direction, and if you change the direction to "RTL", it is taken as an "end margin"!!! and that's very very weird and seems that the new notations in bootstrap 5 like "ms-4", for the preceding bootstrap 4's "ml-4" actually is not so smart! There is no any automagically swapping directions within direction context!

Comment: @Sherveeen i can see what you mean, the wording is wrong, you still need to import bootstrap RTL stylesheet, but the classes used dont change, thanks for letting me know, will add a note redirecting your comment
Edit2: seems i cant actually edit that comment anymore, flag it for moderator attention if you can

Comment: @MarioFigueiredo It seems I could not tell it simple right. I mean, if we are using start prefix for an element, e.g. starting margin, it should be interpreted an start margin for both the RTL and LTR directions. This way I can make a unique design - no matter the direction be - the element will have a starting margin. But unfortunately in Bootstrap 5, when I change direction of my page from LTR to RTL, I'll have to convert all starting notations to endings, and vice versa. So it does not give me a perfect solution to simply change direction and translate texts for a multi-language solution!

Answer (score 9):

Actually the class is like:

{property}{sides}-{size}

Example: mt-1

Answer (score 3):

Tested it but this particular class definition does not work (anymore..) . Think they removed that particular classes.

But e.g. `class="m-y"` does work (in v4.0.0-alpha)

Comment: This is an important note. For example, they changed `m-t-3` to `mt-3`

Answer (score 2):

Spacing utilities that apply to all breakpoints, from xs to xxl, have no breakpoint abbreviation in them. This is because those classes are applied from min-width: 0 and up, and thus are not bound by a media query. The remaining breakpoints, however, do include a breakpoint abbreviation.

The classes are named using the format {property}{sides}-{size} for xs and {property}{sides}-{breakpoint}-{size} for sm, md, lg, xl, and xxl.

Where property is one of:

```
m - for classes that set margin
p - for classes that set padding
```

Where sides is one of:

```
t - for classes that set margin-top or padding-top
b - for classes that set margin-bottom or padding-bottom
s - (start) for classes that set margin-left or padding-left in LTR, margin-right or padding-right in RTL
e - (end) for classes that set margin-right or padding-right in LTR, margin-left or padding-left in RTL
x - for classes that set both *-left and *-right
y - for classes that set both *-top and *-bottom
blank - for classes that set a margin or padding on all 4 sides of the element
```

Where size is one of:

```
0 - for classes that eliminate the margin or padding by setting it to 0
1 - (by default) for classes that set the margin or padding to $spacer * .25
2 - (by default) for classes that set the margin or padding to $spacer * .5
3 - (by default) for classes that set the margin or padding to $spacer
4 - (by default) for classes that set the margin or padding to $spacer * 1.5
5 - (by default) for classes that set the margin or padding to $spacer * 3
auto - for classes that set the margin to auto
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are using **inline** elements.
**Margin top and margin bottom** wont work in **inline** elements.
To make it work, you can change the **display** property of that inline element to **inline-block**.